# How to use AuthenticateOnUnsubscribe flag in Amazon SNS API (JAVA)?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, playframework, amazon-sns

I am working on Java application(Play Framework) which is using Amazon SNS API to send an email to customers. I like to use `AuthenticateOnUnsubscribe` flag for security reason. I donno how to use this flag in java?
When I used `ConfirmSubscription` API in Java, It is asking 'token' value(I donno about this value, It will send from Amazon SNS to customer through email; Not sure; If possible, Advice me)

Advice me on how to use `AuthenticateOnUnsubscribe` flag in Java??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making the "ConfirmSubscription" request authenticated and set the flag.  Instead of just clicking on the email, or going to the confirm URL, use the API call (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/APIReference/API_ConfirmSubscription.html).  Sign it with your AWS key and set the AuthenticateOnUnsubscribe to true.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually In my Java application Im using `SubscribeRequest` to subscribe user from SNS topic. So It sends an email to customer, he needs to confirm it. 
My coding is like this: 
`SubscribeRequest subscribeReq = new SubscribeRequest()
      .withTopicArn(TopicArn)
      .withProtocol(theNotificationType)
      .withEndpoint(emailId);
   AWS_SNS_CREDENTIALS.subscribe(subscribeReq);`

Is there any way to subscribe the user without sending emails to customer? How can we get the token value?

I'm new to Amazon web service. Sorry for asking too much questions.

Comment: The whole point of the token confirmation is to make it so that you cannot subscribe email addresses you don't have access to because of spam reasons.  SNS does not incorporate the trust logic that SES has, so they can't just let you send emails using the service without getting a confirmation from the person who can access the email.

Comment: IMO, SNS is not a good product to use to send emails directly to customers.  It is a nice thing for internal tools to get notifications or to subscribe admins to alerts and stuff.  However, the email offering does not provide the flexibility required to develop an application around it.   Your best bet would be to use SNS for the fanout, and then use SES to actually send you email.  That way you can control the formatting of the email, and the from address, and get bounce notifications and everything else SES provides.